# Disabled selected thead color datatable

Tags: css, datatable

i want to disabled thead color when active/selected, i mean thead color still `#dddfe2` when sorting/thead selected.

The default clor is `#dddfe2` .

[image]

**CSS :**

```
#new-izbox table thead th{
  background: #dddfe2;
  border-left:0px;
  border-right:0px;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddfe2;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #555;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0px;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

*I try something like this, but no luck :*

```
#new-izbox table thead th.selected{
      background: #dddfe2;
      border-left:0px;
      border-right:0px;
      border-top: 0px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #dddfe2;
      text-align: left;
      font-weight: normal;
      color: #555;
      padding:10px;
      margin:0px;
      text-align: left;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Is that a `<select>` element? Do you want to change the color every time you select the dropdown?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thead dataTable

Comment: Which library is this? I don't recognise the `new-izbox` identifier.

Comment: Are you using jQuery Datatable?

Comment: yes im using jquery datatable, i'm using my ID to reduce conflicts with other scripts.

Comment: If you are using the plugin from https://datatables.net/, I don't see a class `selected` there. The class changes from `sorting` for sortable ths to `sorting_asc` or `sorting_desc` if it's sorted on that column.

Comment: Do this `th.sorting_asc, th.sorting_desc { background-color: #dddfe2 !important; }` ...